# ASP.NET - Publishing a web site to IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

What is the difference between publishing a website to {localdrive}\inetpub\wwwroot and anywhere else on the web server e.g. C:\Website.

I have noticed that I am always left with a directory and a website in the IIS console if I publish to {localdrive}\inetpub\wwwroot.

After reading articles on MSDN, I am still unclear of the difference.  I realise that there is probably a simpe answer to this, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web path `/` is already mapped to `c:\inetpub\wwwroot`, so `/abc` is mapped to `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\abc` automatically.

When you publish to `c:\website`, you need to set up a virtual path manually.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing too much as your website path in IIS can point to any directory.  However, that being said always double check your directory permissions and security settings.  In addition, I guess if a hacker did compromised your webserver... the default c:\inetpub\wwwroot is well known.

And just for good measure in case you are having issues - check out the Aspnet_regiis.exe tool on MSDN as it usually solves a lot of issues for folks.

Answer (score 1):

{localdrive}\inetpub\wwwroot is usually used for the default web site that comes with IIS.
Additional Microsoft products use the same directory and take advantage of the virtual directories that exist in the default site.

If this is your personal web site, or a web site you created from scratch, you can publish anywhere you want.

Before you publish, you need to make sure IIS knows where the directory will be, and you need to assign the correct permissions for that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Although they say Virtual Directory created by default for your website in wwwroot and you don't have to configure it again. Many times I found we still have to go there and click on Remove and then click on Create button again :)

Thus it is almost no problem if you create your website outside wwwroot, only difference outside you have to give full path of VD and inside you have to click Remove and then Create button

Answer (score 0):

The default website in IIS is mapped to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` by default, so publishing to `wwwroot` makes it easy to add applications as virtual directories.

However, you can publish wherever you like, and either point a virtual directory or new website at your publication location. You simply need to make sure user the App Pool is running as (usually `IUSR` under IIS7, `IUSR_MachineName` under previous versions) has read/execute permissions on the folder you are publishing to.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had was different from all of the above. I was trying to publish in "C:\inetpub\wwwroot" and the publish failed every time. Than i changed the publish folder to another and it worked. When I launched visual studio as administrator I could copy to C:\inetpub\wwwroot also without problems